# Generate random number - Higher value

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have this:

```
int minValue = int.Parse(min.Text);
int maxValue = int.Parse(max.Text);
Random rnd = new Random();
int final = rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue);
result.Text = final.ToString("");
```

I'm going to get the two values (lower value and higher value) to two textboxes. These values are entered by the user. When I generate the random number, in no situation does the higher value appear. For example, the user enters 1 and 5. I repeatedly generate a number and in no situation does the number 5 appear. It only appears either 1, or 2, or 3, or 4, not 5. Why?

Comment: also don't create `Random` right before using it. have it in field. and use that instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at function docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

The higher value is **exclusive**.

To include it you need to do :

```
int final = rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue+1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem and clarifies my doubt.

Answer (score 8):

Because Random.Next gives random value **exclusive** upper bound.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
int minValue = int.Parse(min.Text);
int maxValue = int.Parse(max.Text)+1;
Random rnd = new Random();
int final = rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue);
result.Text = final.ToString("");
```

This will work because when it takes maxvalue range starts from minValue to maxValue-1.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem and clarifies my doubt.